# How to display message from BindingResult.reject("message") in thymeleaf page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to show the message thrown by `bindingresult.reject("message")` on my web page.

```java
if (product.getQuantity() < saleDetailDto.getQuantity()) {
    bindingResult.reject("Not enough item in inventory");
    return "purchase-detail/save-form";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to determine for which field you reject.

The [`rejectValue()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method is used to add a validation error to the [`BindingResult`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) object.

**The first parameter** identifies which field the error is associated with.

**The second parameter** is an error code which acts a message key for the `messages.properties` file (or `messages_en.properties` or `messages_fr.properties` etc., if these are being used).

**The third parameter** of `rejectValue()` represents the fallback default message, which is displayed if no matching error code is found in the resource bundle.

```java
if(product.getQuantity() < saleDetailDto.getQuantity()){
    bindingResult.rejectValue("quantity", "error.quantity", "Not enough item in inventory!");
    return "purchase-detail/save-form";
}
```

To show it on html, you can do as follows.

```html
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('quantity')}" th:errors="*{quantity}">Error!</span>
```