# Thymeleaf and @Uniqueconstraint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I want to ask how to handle uniquecontraint exception at thymeleaf. To handle excpetion I am using this:

```
<span th:style="'color:red'" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userName')}" th:errors="*{userName}">Name Error</span>
```

It handles lenght exception and not null, but why it fail with uniqe constraint, my entity looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Users")
@Table(
        name = "\"users\"",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint( name = "users_username_unique", columnNames = "user_name")
        }
)
public class Users {

...

    @Column(
            name = "user_name",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT",
            updatable = false
    )
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*User name is too short")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Enter user name")
    private String userName;

...
}
```

Comment: What happens when the unique constraint validation should trigger? Did you apply the unique constraint in the database?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe It throws an exception. At the database it saves automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unique columns will be used only in `DDL generation`, it doesn't have any impact during runtime.** The actual uniqueness checks happens in the database.

I can suggest method for you to do this. **The method is to check if this username is available** and you can make an error accordingly, s an example, it could be a code like this:

```java
Optional<Users> optionalUser = userRepository.findByUserName(..);
if(optionalUser.isPresent()){
    bindingResult.rejectValue("userName", "error.userName", "You cannot use this username!");
    return "form";
}
```

More information about the `BindingResult` class and the `rejectValue()` method, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759773/2039546

`OR`

Other of the possible solutions is to create custom annotation and validator, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4733441/2039546